# Complete CSS Reset for small subset of tags

Tags: html, css, firefox, reset

I'm working on a Firefox extension that injects bits and pieces of HTML into web pages that users normally browse. These bits and pieces need to be styled properly and consistently across all possible pages that a user might visit. Which means that the CSS rules should override all possible modifications that any web developer might think of. At the same time only a small subset of HTML elements is used in the injected markup: `div, a, p, span, table, tr, td`.

What I'm loking for is a complete CSS Reset stylesheet that will take care of all possible intrusions that host page might make to the injected markup. Is there such a stylesheet?

To clarify: I want to make sure that the following rules wont screw up my injected markup: `p { color: red }` or `p { transform: rotate(7.5deg); }`

Comment: The injected bits and pieces are really small - markers for links on the page, so I'd prefer to avoid using iframes...

Answer (score 1):

The "standard style" area can be wrapped in an un-reset class using this stylesheet. The issue is you'll need to inject the stylesheet along with the HTML.

https://github.com/jbcrawford/Un-ResetStylesheet

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for Firefox, you can probably use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getDefaultComputedStyle to construct this stylesheet...